# How to easily collapse vertical space around label when its text is nil?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Suppose I have three labels that are laid out below each other in a column. The uppermost label's top edge is pinned to the superview's top edge. All following labels' top edges are pinned to the preceding label's bottom edge. The leading and trailing edges of all labels are pinned to the leading and trailing edge of the superview. Here's what it looks like in Interface Builder (I added a blue background on every label to visualize its extent).

[image: Screenshot showing labels in interface builder]

In the simulator the result looks like this.

[image: Simulator screenshot showing three labels]

All labels are connected to outlets in a view controller.

```
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
```

When I set the text of `label2` to `nil`

```
label2.text = nil
```

the label itself collapses.

[image: Simulator screenshot showing the collapsed middle label]

However, the top and bottom spaces around the label do not collapse. This is evident by the fact that there is no blue background on the middle label in the last screenshot. As a result, the space between `label1` and `label3` is double the space of the layout in the first screenshot.

My question is - **on iOS8** - what is the easiest way to collapse either the middle label's top or bottom space so that the two remaining labels still use the vertical spacing defined in the original layout? To be clear, this is the result I want to achieve.

[image: Simulator screenshot showing reduced spacing between the two remaining labels]

Options I've found so far:

### Bottom/Top Spacing Constraint Outlet

Define an outlet for the middle label's top or bottom spacing constraint.

```
@IBOutlet weak var spacingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Store the constraint's initial constant into a variable (e.g. in `awakeFromNib` or `viewDidLoad`).

```
private var initialSpacing: CGFloat!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    initialSpacing = spacingConstraint.constant
    ...
```

Set the constraint's constant to zero whenever the text is set to `nil` or back to its initial value when the text is not `nil`.

```
spacingConstraint.constant = label2.text == nil ? 0 : initialSpacing
```

This approach feels a bit clumsy since it requires two additional variables.

### Height Constraint Outlet

Set the vertical spacing around the middle label to zero and increase its height by the same amount. Define an outlet for the height constraint and proceed as above, setting the height to zero when the text is `nil` and back to it's initial value when the height is not `nil`.

This is still as clumsy as the previous approach. In addition, you have to hardcode the spacing and cannot use the built-in default spacings (blank fields in Interface builder).

### UIStackView

This is not an option since `UIStackView` is only available on iOS 9 and above.

Comment: Have you ever think about using tableview?? I think the table view is made for those kind of situation :)

Comment: You can disable scrolling.

Comment: @JasonNam Using a table view might be a solution. There is, however, a certain amount of overhead (implementing data source methods) associated with it.

Comment: maybe refreshing the constraints? something like `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` after checking that label2 = nil;?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using [this](https://github.com/forkingdog/UIView-FDCollapsibleConstraints) UIView category for this purpose.

It extends `UIView` by adding  two more property named `fd_collapsed` and `fd_collapsibleConstraints` using objective-c runtime framework. You simply drag constraints that you want to be disabled when `fd_collapsed` property set to `YES`. Behind the scene, it captures the initial value of these constraints, then set to zero whenever `fd_collapsed` is YES. Reset to initial values when `fd_collapsed` is NO.

There is also another property called `fd_autocollapsed`

> Not every view needs to add a width or height constraint, views like UILabel, UIImageView have their Intrinsic content size when they have content in it. For these views, we provide a Auto collapse property, when its content is gone, selected constraints will collapse automatically.

This property automatically sets `fd_collapsed` property to YES whenever specified view has content to display.

It's really simple to use. It's kinda shame that there is no builtin solution like that.

Comment: Sweet, that looks very promising.

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions are good enough for me and I'd do Bottom/Top Spacing Constraint Outlet solution but since you want something different. You can use this third party: https://github.com/orta/ORStackView It has iOS7+ support and do exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider that.

Answer (score 0):

This is low-key a pain all perfectionist devs learn about when trying to stack a bunch of labels. Solutions can get too verbose, annoying to folow, and really annoying to implement (ie. keeping a reference to the top constraint... gets annoying once you do it multiple times, or just change the order of the labels)

Hopefully my code below puts an end to this:

```
class MyLabel: UILabel {

    var topPadding: CGFloat = 0

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        var newRect = rect
        newRect.origin.y += topPadding/2

        super.drawText(in: newRect)
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var newIntrisicSize = super.intrinsicContentSize

        guard newIntrisicSize != .zero else {
            return .zero
        }

        newIntrisicSize.height += topPadding
        return newIntrisicSize
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let label = MyLabel()
label.topPadding = 10    
// then use autolayout to stack your labels with 0 offset
```

Granted, its only for top padding, but that should be the only thing you need to layout your labels properly. It works great with or without autolayout. Also its a big plus not needing to do any extra mental gymnastics just to do something so simple. Enjoy!